# Karma Unit Test cannot serialize cyclic structure

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner, stringify

I am using Karma to write unit tests for my angular code. I have the following test which fails:

```
it('handles a successful log in', function() {
    $scope.login(user);

    deferred.resolve({data: {data: {id: 1}}});
    $scope.$apply();

    //expect(api.post).toHaveBeenCalledWith('authentication/login', user, true);
    //expect(api.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith('hd/permissions');
    //expect($state.go).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

This is the error I get:

```
Running "karma:unit" (karma) task
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8 0.0.0) ERROR
    TypeError: JSON.stringify cannot serialize cyclic structures.
    at c:/Users/mabj/AppData/Local/Temp/node_modules/core-js/modules/es6.symbol.js:224:0 <- C:/Users/mabj/AppData/Local/Temp/a3d3ad3841dd260581022edde320b394.browserify:83092
```

However, if I change the fourth line in the code to `deferred.reject({data: {data: {id: 1}}});` the test succeeds. People in my team developing using Apple computers can also run this test without failing. Noone in my team knows why it fails on my computer.

Does anyone here know why it fails or what I might try do make it succeed?